# How to make a choropleth map with a regional shapefile & data? (no global worldmap or continental)

Tags: visualization, geography

I have a regional map in a shapefile with datanames and similar, but I can´t use it with data and making a [`choropleth map`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map). I can´t use the names of each region inside the shapefile. I don´t know how to assign data to each region.

I can only import the region data to a graph.

I can´t assign data to each region, I can´t print the name of each region.
Question 1.- How to assign data to each of the 51 regions?
Question 2.- How to obtain a choropleth map?

```
Directory[]
SetDirectory["d:\Users\..."]
estradamap = Import["estrada.zip"]
```

[image]

The shapefile (and dbf and shx) is at https://we.tl/t-7gtTLQPjfA

Question 3.-How to extract the data at .dbf file to a Table[] ?

Comment: does `Import["estrada.zip", "Data"]` give what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt = Import["estrada.zip", "Data"];
polygons = "Geometry" /. dt[[1]];
labels = "PARROQUIA" /. ("LabeledData" /. dt[[1]]);
values = "SUPERFICIE" /. ("LabeledData" /. dt[[1]]);
Graphics[{{Hue[#], Tooltip[#2, Column[{#3, "SUPERFICIE : " <> ToString@#4}]]} & @@@ 
   Transpose[{Rescale@values, polygons, labels, values}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
estradamap = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/estrada.zip"];

data = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/Estrada.zip", "Data"];
```

Get names of parishes

```
names = Cases[data, HoldPattern[Rule["PARROQUIA", names_List]] :> names, 
    Infinity][[1]];
```

Get surface areas

```
areas = Cases[data, HoldPattern[Rule["SUPERFICIE", areas_List]] :> areas, 
    Infinity][[1]];

{minArea, maxArea} = MinMax[areas]

(* {100.076, 2150.27} *)

cf = "TemperatureMap"; (* color function *)
```

Names and areas are placed in [`Tooltip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)

```
n = 1; (* index *)
Legended[
 estradaChoroplethMap = 
  estradamap /. 
   Polygon[pts_] :> {ColorData[cf][Rescale[areas[[n]], {minArea, maxArea}]], ,
      Tooltip[Polygon[pts], names[[n]] <> "\n" <> ToString[areas[[n++]]]]}, 
 BarLegend[{cf, {minArea, maxArea}}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For a table of the data

```
{names, (NumberForm[#, {7, 3}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}] & /@ areas)} // 
   Transpose // 
  Prepend[#, (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"PARROQUIA", "SUPERFICIE"})] & // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left] &
```